# How do I add a full-stop at the end of this printed list?

Tags: python, list, punctuation

```
start_year = int(input("Enter start year:"))
end_year = int(input("Enter end year:"))

mylist = []

for year in range(start_year,end_year):
    if ((year % 4 == 0) and (year % 100 != 0)) or (year % 400 == 0):
        mylist.append(int(year))


for i in range(0, len(mylist), 10):
    print(*mylist[i:i+10], sep=', ')
```

Comment: You want something like: `2000, 2004, .` ?

Answer (score 1):

Change the `end` argument of the `print` function from its default value of `'\n'`. Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print

Try this:

```
print(*mylist[i:i+10], sep=', ', end='.\n')
```